# Cloud function onUpdate is not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am new to javascript and google cloud functions. I followed the documentation and still don't know why orderdata is returning undefined.

```
exports.updateordersumry = functions.database.ref('/Ordergroup/{pushId}/OrderSummry').onUpdate(event => {

            const orderdata = event.data.val();
            const isbuyercharged = orderdata.buyercharged
})
```

orderdata is returning undefined, what am i doing wrongly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this:

```
exports.updateordersumry = functions.database.ref('/Ordergroup/{pushId}/OrderSummry').onUpdate(event => {

        const orderdata = event.data.val();
        const isbuyercharged = orderdata.buyercharged
})
```

into this:

```
exports.updateordersumry = functions.database.ref('/Ordergroup/{pushId}/OrderSummry').onUpdate((change,context) => {

        const orderdata = change.after.val();
        const isbuyercharged = orderdata.buyercharged
})
```

The cloud functions were updated, thus now `onUpdate` has two parameters `change` and `context`, to be able to retrieve the updated data, you need to use `change.after.val()`.

More info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#realtime-database